# iPhone 6 Plus Autolayout issue with UISplitViewController and UISearchController during rotation

Tags: ios, autolayout, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller, iphone-6-plus

Auto layout is not working properly on iOS 8/9 when `UISearchController` is presented on master in a `UISplitViewController` interface.

To reproduce this issue:

1. Create a new Master-Detail Application in Xcode (using swift, no core data)
2. Add `var searchController: UISearchController!` to `MasterViewController`
3. Add the following under `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
   searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
   definesPresentationContext = true
   tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
   ```
4. Run the application on iPhone 6 Plus or simulator
5. Rotate to landscape.
6. Tap the "+" button and select the item so that the detail updates
7. Tap the search bar to present it in the navigation bar
8. Rotate back to portrait, the detail should now take up the full screen.
9. Navigate back to master (tap "< Master")
10. Dismiss the search (tap "Cancel")
11. Rotate back to landscape

Now you can see the `UISearchBar` is out of alignment.

[image: Master Detail Application]

We can verify this in the view debugger:

[image: View Debugger]

This issue is more apparent if you click the "show clipped content" button:

[image]

It's not just the `UISearchBar` that is misaligned, but the entire MasterViewController.

I have reproduced this issue in the native mail and messages app as well:

[image: iOS Mail App]

[image: iOS Messages App]

> Has anyone found a work around or solution to this particular issue?

Answer (score 1):

The only acceptable solution I have found so far is to implement the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` method:

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
    collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController,
    ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

Don't forget to set the split view controller's delegate.

While this may not be the desired collapsing behavior, it does seem to prevent auto layout issues.